# C# client socket multiple send and receive

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I am using sockets for TCP-IP connection and I would like to establish simple system send-receive from the client side.

```
 Socket sck;
        sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        IPEndPoint localEndpt = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("123.123.123.1"), 12345);
        try
        {
            sck.Connect(localEndpt);
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.Write("Unable to Connect");
        }
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Text");
            string sendtext = Console.ReadLine();
            byte[] Data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sendtext);
            sck.Send(Data);
            Console.WriteLine("Data Sent!");

            byte[] bytesReceived = new byte[sck.ReceiveBufferSize];
            int bytes = 0;
            String strReceived = "";

            int dataAvailable = 0;
            while (dataAvailable == 0 || dataAvailable != sck.Available)
            {
                dataAvailable = sck.Available;
                Thread.Sleep(100); // if no new data after 100ms assume transmission finished
            }

            if (sck.Available > 0)
            {
                bytes = sck.Receive(bytesReceived, bytesReceived.Length, 0);
                strReceived+=Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesReceived, 0, bytes);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Received from server: " + strReceived);
        }
        Console.Read();
```

The problem is that first requests goes throught but the second does not, because socket is not available anymore (socket "Availabe" attribute value is 0). What am I doing wrong? What would be the easiest way to establish multiple send-recieve requests (in order)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This code works fine for me**

```
    private List<Socket> _clients = new List<Socket>();
    private Thread _dataReceiveThread;
    private bool _isConnected;

    private void DataReceive()
    {
        while (_isConnected)
        {
            List<Socket> clients = new List<Socket>(_clients);
            foreach (Socket client in clients)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (!client.Connected) continue;
                    string txt = "";
                    while (client.Available > 0)
                    {
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
                        int byteRec = client.Receive(bytes);
                        if (byteRec > 0)
                            txt += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, byteRec);
                    }
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt))
                        /* TODO: access the text received with "txt" */
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Exception_Handler(e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Just run this code to get started**

```
_isConnected = true;
_dataReceiveThread = new Thread(DataReceive);
_dataReceiveThread.Start();
```

**Update list box in `Cross thread`**:

This code can be placed in the comment section.

```
myListBox1.Invoke((Action)(() => { myListBox1.Items.Add(txt) }));
```

Answer (score 1):

`Socket. Available` does *NOT* indicate whether the socket is available, but incoming data is available for reading:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee425135.aspx

Your program quits because it checks for a reply (incoming data) immediately after sending a message out. Use a `Thread.Sleep` before checking for data.

Maybe the message has not even been sent, because `Socket.Send` just places it in the network interface card's output buffer. When the socket finally sends the message, it will upare the connection state. If it got no reply (on a TCP connection), it will tell you that it is disconnected when you query the state. On UDP it will tell you nothing, because UDP is connectionless.